# All Retrofit 2 POST requests timing out and server receiving empty strings

Tags: android, express, retrofit, okhttp

I followed the guide on [codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit) to implement a POST request with retrofit. All seems good, except all requests are throwing `timeout` error, and they seem to have empty bodies. I don't understand how the server would register a request if there was a timeout to begin with, besides the fact that empty body requests aren't too helpful for my purposes.

I tried to configure my retrofit client with an okhttp with a timeout of 60 seconds which I thought was [more than] sufficient but this doesn't solve the timeout issue. The objects being passed to the retrofit api service are non-null and populated. The guide on codepath mentions that retrofit automatically converts objects to JSON using the gson configured with it. So I don't think conversion is causing any problems, and I tried sending actual JSON strings to confirm.

Please see the relevant pieces of code below for reference. I would appreciate any help with the issues of 1) requests timing out every time and 2) sending bodies with empty strings :)

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    // Trailing slash is needed
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.hidden-for-privacy.com/";

    public static final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    public static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
            .create();

    public static Retrofit instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    public static ApiEndpointInterface service =
            instance.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class ApiService {
    ApiEndpointInterface request;

    public ApiService() {
        request = RetrofitClient.service;
    }

    public void createDamage(Damage damage) {
        Log.d("ApiService.createDamage", RetrofitClient.gson.toJson(damage));

        Call<Damage> call = request.createDamage(damage);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Damage>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Damage> call, Response<Damage> response) {
                Log.d("ApiService post-damage success", response.message());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Damage> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ApiService post-damage fail", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public interface ApiEndpointInterface {
    // Request method and URL specified in the annotation
    @POST("api/damages/damage")
    Call<Damage> createDamage(@Body Damage damage);
}
```

Comment: did you add "@SerializedName" for each of the parameters in the POJO?

Comment: The timeout error is because the server did not send a response. You won't get timeout error if the server sent some error if it received an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @rya, I have been able to deal with the timeout error. All fields in the `Damage` class do have `@SerializedName(fieldname)` annotation, where fieldname is the variable name of the field. I auto-generated the class with https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ so they also have `@Expose` annotation. I have yet to deal with receiving empty strings though.

Comment: does it only happen for this request or for all requests? Could you try with a GET request?